# Set tax on product subtotal line at checkout

Tags: tax, totals, onestepcheckout

I'm struggling to set the correct price on the checkout summery.
[image]

What I need is the price on each product lines (red) should include Tax, like the Subtotal (blue). In the images, the 2 highlighted amounts should be $682.95.

I tried configuring Tax on the Admin Configuration, but it doesn't seem to want to change anything.

If it helps, I'm using onestepcheckout, but not sure it changes anything.

Comment: What setting do you have in System > Tax > Calculation Settings > Catalog Price?

Comment: Calculation Settings > Catalog Prices => Excluding Tax |

Shopping Cart Display Settings:
Display Prices => Including Tax
Display Subtotal => Including Tax 
Display Shipping Amount => Including Tax
Display Gift Wrapping Prices => Excluding Tax
Display Printed Card Prices => Excluding Tax

Comment: The Catalog price should be Including Tax. Try this solution

Comment: Display Product Prices In Catalog was already Inc. Tax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after searching for a while directly in the code.
Like @Giuseppe suggested, it didn't come from Magento but from the template (in this case the module OneStepCheckout from Idev).
Instead of using the Magento configuration (Like good developers would have done), they put their own configuration deeply hidden!
That configuration is in System>Configuration>OneStepCheckout>General>Display amounts incl. tax And you put it to yes.

So I have no idea why they did that, but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should check "System > Tax >Shopping Cart Display Setting" 
In that section you can set how price are displayed on the cart. 
(this section's settings does not affect how the price are calculated).

Comment: Tried all combinations and doesn't work.

Comment: Try to display both price incl. and excl. tax in this way you can verify if the calculations are correct.
Let us know what you get.

Comment: Doesn't change that price... But I noticed that it says that it includes tax, so maybe it's along the way that the calculation is wrong. I will check the deep code to see what causes that to happen.

Comment: you should see two different price one with taxes and one without, if you does not see the two prices maybe is the template that is not compliant to the magento standards